# Lo que pasa es que android studio no me reconoce el dispositivo fisico

Tags: java, android, android-studio, adb, emulación

Buenas los que pasa es que al conectar mi dispositivo Samsung j1  físico para probar mis aplicaciones en android studio, no me reconoce el dispositivo y no me sale nada, nose si tengo los SDK que son[image: NO me reconoce el dispositivo]:
[image: SDK que tengo instalados]

Agradecería bastante a quien me pudiera ayudar.
Gracias

Comment: Debes activar las opciones de desarrollador en el dispositivo y otorgar algunos permisos como depuración USB y otros. ¿Ya lo hiciste?

Comment: si ya esta habilitado las opciones de desarrollador

Comment: ¿Qué dispositivo es el que estas intentando conectar?

Comment: Estoy utilizando un Samsung j1